# How to use a .TTF font that .NET says "Is not a truetype font" in a .NET program?

Tags: fonts, .net-4.0, truetype

I have downloaded a font, [Betsy Flanagan][1], that I'd like to use in my program that shows on-screen keyboard shortcuts and their meaning in various programs.

However, when selecting the font in Visual Studio 2010 for a label, I get an error message that says "Only TrueType fonts are supported. This is not a TrueType font."

Is there any way for me to display text with this font in a .NET program? Since this is a specialized toast-like form, with just one label that needs to have this particular font, I don't really care if it is a hack to do it (like P/Invoke or similar.)

**Note**: This is a .NET 4.0 Winforms application.

Comment: WPF? WinForms? ASP.NET? Can you use bitmaps instead?

Comment: WinForms, and that would mean I have to render all the font bitmaps somehow. Not the solution I would like, but if that's the only way to do it I might look into it.

Comment: Try running it through some TTF conversion programs to make it usable.

Comment: ... because those freebies are quite old: *From 1996-2001, Ray Larabie created a collection of 383 free fonts*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If [this is the font you're trying to use](http://desktoppub.about.com/library/fonts/dd/uc_betsyflanagan.htm), then maybe your local instance is corrupt?

VS2010 was well behaved when I tried to set labels and other winforms controls to Betsy. Download the one I linked and see if that works. My take is that if you've got a valid TTF installed, VS isn't going to take exception.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this code that loads an embedded font as a resource and used in controls where applicable, the sample shows the usage of embedding an OCR font

```
    private PrivateFontCollection pfc = new PrivateFontCollection();
    private Font _fntOCRFont = null;
    private enum FontEnum{
       OCR = 0
    };

    private FontSize _fntSizeDefault = FontSize.Small;
    private float _fFontSize = 0.0F;

    private void InitOCRFont(){
        try{
            System.IO.Stream streamFont = this.GetType().Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("ocraext.ttf");
            if (streamFont != null){
                byte[] fontData = new byte[streamFont.Length];
                streamFont.Read(fontData, 0, (int)streamFont.Length);
                streamFont.Close();
                unsafe{
                    fixed(byte *pFontData = fontData){
                    this.pfc.AddMemoryFont((System.IntPtr)pFontData, fontData.Length);
                }
            }
        }else{
            throw new Exception("Error! Could not read built-in Font.");
        }
    }catch(Exception eX){
        throw new Exception("Exception was: " + eX.Message);
    }
}

private void ConvertFontEnumToFloat(){
    switch(this._fntSizeDefault){
        case FontSize.Small :
            this._fFontSize = 8.0F;
            break;
        case FontSize.Medium :
            this._fFontSize = 10.0F;
            break;
        case FontSize.Large :
            this._fFontSize = 12.0F;
            break;
    }
}
```

Typical invocation of the code would be something like this:

```
this.ConvertFontEnumToFloat();
this._fntOCRFont = new Font(this.pfc.Families[(int)FontEnum.OCR], this._fFontSize, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold);
if (this._fntOCRFont != null){
   // Do something here... perhaps assign it to a control
}
```

The function `InitOCRFont` uses unsafe which means having the `unsafe` compiler option switched on, reads from the embedded resource and loads into a `PrivateFontCollection`. The function `ConvertFontEnumToFloat` uses a hardcoded float value to indicate the size based on the enum of the font. When finished with the code, be sure to dispose of the `PrivateFontCollection` instance in the `Dispose` method of designated class.